# Table Layout Panel Wrong Column ordering

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

i have a table layoutpanel in my form. it has a few rows (filled with controls):

```
label10   ---   textbox10     ----    label20
label11   ---    textbox11   ---    label21
label12    ---   textbox12   ---    label22
label13    ---   textbox13    ---   label23
label14    ---   textbox14    ---   label24
```

now i want to add new row in the middle of table using this code:

```
myLayoutpanel.Controls.Add(label333, 0, 3);

myLayoutpanel.Controls.Add(textbox333, 0, 3);

myLayoutpanel.Controls.Add(label444, 0, 3);
```

it will add a new row after line3.
usually the result is in the true order:

```
label333   ---   textbox333   ---   label444
```

but for some rows it seems wrong: for example if the addition take place after line 4 :

```
label444  ---    label333   ---   textbox333
```

Comment: each time running the code i see same result in same row position (only on that row)

Comment: i realized an interesting point in this problem: suppose that the table has 12 rows, the row in the middle (row 6) has different column ordering. rows 1-5 are in same format and between rows 7-12 the middle row (9) get the same ordering with 6 and so on: finaly rows 6, 9 , 11 are in a different column ordering.

Answer (score 3):

You're not going crazy. This is a bug introduced in the .NET Framework 4.5. See references at

[A .NET 4.5 incompatibility](http://roman.st/Article/Another-NET-4.5-incompatibility)

and

[System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel Behavior Change .NET 4.5 Framework](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767282/system-windows-forms-tablelayoutpanel-behavior-change-net-4-5-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happened to you as you post no evidence. But please check if this code execute correctly. I conjecture that your codes hadn't executed in right order.

```
myLayoutpanel.Controls.Add(label333, 0, 3); 
Thread.Sleep(100); 
myLayoutpanel.Controls.Add(textbox333, 0, 3); 
Thread.Sleep(100); 
myLayoutpanel.Controls.Add(label444, 0, 3);
```

Comment: I think the best approach is to change your plan. I mean is it the only way of implementing your program? Posting your program purpose may help.